# Write text under the cursor to new file and delete it form current file

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, visual-mode

I have this in my vimrc:

```
" Export text under the cursor
noremap <leader>e :w! >><Space>
```

This allows me to select text using visual mode, press `leader e`, type a file name, and append the text under the cursor to that file.

I would like to also have the text under the cursor be deleted from the current file as part of this command, but I don't know how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are using this mapping line-wise by selecting lines with `V` before executing `<leader>e`. This is worth a `command` in my opinion.

```
command! -range=% -nargs=1 -complete=file MoveTo
        \ <line1>,<line2>write! >> <args> | <line1>,<line2>d_
```

- `-range=%` to allow a range, if none, consider the whole buffer
- `-nargs=1 -complete=file` accept one argument and allow file completion for it
- `MoveTo` name of the command...
- `<line1>,<line2>write! >> <args>` append lines from the range to the given argument
- `| <line1>,<line2>d_` then delete the lines in the black hole register so that they aren't copied in `""`

Then

```
xnoremap <leader>e :MoveTo<Space>
nnoremap <leader>e :MoveTo<Space>
```

[`:h user-commands`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#user-commands), [`:h quote_`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#quote_)

Comment: Thanks! This as even better functionality that I anticipated and I appreciate your explanation. I have been using `ed` recently and I have been interested in learning ex mode to replace it.

Comment: Note that I added the `=%` to `-range` to be consistent with your original mapping, but a maybe more intuitive definition could be simply `-range` to apply on the current line by default in normal mode.